# Creating functions containing HTML

Tags: javascript, html, string, function, coffeescript

I'm trying to create a Coffescript function that contains common HTML for a frequently re-used object in my page. I'm passing a variable to the function with the text I want changed each time. Every time I try to compile my Coffeescript, I get this error:

```
[stdin]:6:5: error: unexpected identifier
<p>"text1"</p>
    ^^^^^
```

Here's my code

```
text1 = "Some text"

ballon1 = (text1) ->
"<a href=\"#balloon1\">Open Modal</a>
<blockquote class=\"balloon\" id=\"balloon1\">
<p>"text1"</p>
<a href=\"#close\" title=\"Close\" class=\"close\">X</a>
</blockquote>"
```

I was hoping the output would be:

```
<a href="#balloon1">Open Modal</a>
<blockquote class="balloon" id="balloon1\">
<p>Some text</p>
<a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
</blockquote>
```

Any thoughts? I was trying to find the language for the job; maybe I should be using PHP instead? Also, I'm using Javascript because I thought the code needed to be run client-side, since I want to pass different text to the function depending on what links are clicked and when.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is CoffeeScript, you can use [string interpolation](http://coffeescript.org/#strings):

```
ballon1 = (text1) ->
  "<a href=\"#balloon1\">Open Modal</a>
  <blockquote class=\"balloon\" id=\"balloon1\">
  <p>#{text1}</p>
  <a href=\"#close\" title=\"Close\" class=\"close\">X</a>
  </blockquote>"
```

You could also switch to single quotes in your HTML to avoid all the backslashes:

```
ballon1 = (text1) ->
  "<a href='#balloon1'>Open Modal</a>
  <blockquote class='balloon' id='balloon1'>
  <p>#{text1}</p>
  <a href='#close' title='Close' class='close'>X</a>
  </blockquote>"
```

Or, if you're like me a think single quotes look funny in HTML, you could use a block string for your HTML snippet:

```
ballon1 = (text1) ->
  """
    <a href="#balloon1">Open Modal</a>
    <blockquote class="balloon" id="balloon1">
      <p>#{text1}</p>
      <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
    </blockquote>
  """
```

A block string even lets you nicely indent the HTML for readability. This is the version I'd probably go with.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder There's even a [regex version](http://coffeescript.org/#regexes) (similar to Perl's `/x` modifier) which is an even better idea.

Comment: I am not a fan of CoffeeScript, but these are *nice*. I'm glad JavaScript is getting [template strings](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-template-literal-lexical-components). :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have sort of a love/hate relationship with CoffeeScript. The indentation thing and everyone trying to avoid parentheses, brackets, and braces everywhere bug me. I'm not so sure about [tagged template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings#Tagged_template_strings) in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

If you want string concatenation, you want the `+` operator:

```
ballon1 = (text1) ->
  "<a href=\"#balloon1\">Open Modal</a>
  <blockquote class=\"balloon\" id=\"balloon1\">
  <p>" + text1 + "</p>
  <a href=\"#close\" title=\"Close\" class=\"close\">X</a>
  </blockquote>"
```

Change is on the fourth line.

That said, you might consider looking into templating libraries if this is something that comes up a lot. That way (with many of them) you can author your templates in an HTML editor, embedding them in your page, and not have to fuss about with quote character escaping.

Comment: OK, thank you so much. That solves my problem. I'll look into some templating libraries as well.